# What are the IP ranges to block the entire Russian Federation?

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, iptables, blocking

Every single morning the Russian Federation keeps attacking our sites. Every single day I block their IP address and every single day they use a new sub net. I tried:

```
-A INPUT -s 4.53.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 173.205.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 37.9.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 213.180.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 5.255.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 141.8.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 87.250.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 178.154.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 5.45.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

How do I block the entire Russian Federation IP ranges in my iptables?

Comment: Your `Edit` catches the ranges I mentioned, but there are many more (by my count, 45,324,032 addresses in 7,255 blocks) if you want to block all the Russian Federation.

Comment: Finally how did the attacks stopped? I am facing same problem since last 2 days.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**7,255 IP address blocks assigned to the Russian Federation**

As of June 2018, there are over 7,200 IPv4 address blocks assigned to the Russian Federation. The largest of them, with 524,288 addresses each, are: `5.136.0.0/13`, `95.24.0.0/13`, `176.208.0.0/13`, and `178.64.0.0/13`.

However, some of the IP ranges you've blocked are not assigned to the Russian Federation, but attacks may come from anywhere just as easily. It's common for attackers to spoof IP addresses or to use a botnet (a network of Internet-connected devices infected with malicious software and controlled as a group without the owners' knowledge).

In fact, the 16,777,216 addresses in `4.0.0.0/8`, and the 131,072 addresses in `173.204.0.0/15` are assigned to the United States of America.

The `37.9.0.0/16` addresses are assigned in these blocks:

```
  37.9.0.0/20  4096 RU Russian Federation
 37.9.16.0/20  4096 KZ Kazakhstan
 37.9.32.0/20  4096 RU Russian Federation
 37.9.48.0/21  2048 RU Russian Federation
 37.9.56.0/21  2048 GB United Kingdom
 37.9.64.0/18 16384 RU Russian Federation
37.9.128.0/21  2048 RU Russian Federation
37.9.136.0/21  2048 FR France
37.9.144.0/20  4096 RU Russian Federation
37.9.160.0/21  2048 NL Netherlands
37.9.168.0/21  2048 SK Slovakia
37.9.176.0/21  2048 CY Cyprus
37.9.184.0/21  2048 DE Germany
37.9.192.0/21  2048 CZ Czechia
37.9.200.0/21  2048 TR Turkey
37.9.208.0/21  2048 HU Hungary
37.9.216.0/21  2048 NL Netherlands
37.9.224.0/20  4096 IT Italy
37.9.240.0/21  2048 RU Russian Federation
37.9.248.0/21  2048 IR Iran
```

Similarly, the `213.180.0.0/16`, `5.255.0.0/16`, `141.8.0.0/16`, `87.250.0.0/16`, and`5.45.0.0/16` blocks are assigned multiple countries.

The `178.154.0.0/16` block is assigned to:

```
  178.154.0.0/17 32768 BY Belarus
178.154.128.0/17 32768 RU Russian Federation
```

Generally, targeting a `/16` block of addresses is not the correct range. In practical terms, it's not possible to block every address assigned to the Russian Federation, and as your list shows, attacks can come from almost anywhere.

**Example: How to find a block for an IP address**

Find the IP block for address `37.9.10.64`, assuming a typical version of the command-line tool `whois`.

1. Find the Regional Internet Registry for the address with `whois -a 37.9.10.64`. The listing shows that the address is assigned to the European registry with `whois` service at `whois.ripe.net`.
2. Look up the address block for IP `37.9.10.64` with `whois -h whois.ripe.net 37.9.10.64`. The listing shows that `37.9.0.0/20` is assigned to CTV Dominanta Ltd in Russia.

**Regional Internet Registries**

Current IP assignments are available from the Regional Internet Registries:

- http://www.apnic.net - Asia Pacific
- http://www.ripe.net - Europe
- http://www.arin.net - North America
- http://www.lacnic.net - Latin America
- http://www.afrinic.net - Africa and Indian Ocean

Comment: Where did you get the nice block break-up by assignments from?

Comment: @AlexO The assignments themselves come from text files that are available by FTP from each of the registries. I used a Perl module, [IP::Country::DB_File::Builder](https://metacpan.org/pod/IP::Country::DB_File::Builder) to create a country-to-IP address reference.